# Предотвращение загрузки после пересоздания фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-loader

Есть `ViewPager`, который "держит" в себе 4 фрагмента. Так как использую `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` фрагменты пересоздаются, следовательно сохраняю в `Bundle` текущую загруженную страницу. Но при возвращении на фрагмент идет снова загрузка и загружаются те же данные. Для примера: если остановится на 5-й странице, то при возвращении загрузчик снова загрузит 5 страницу. Как это предотвратить?

```
public abstract class MovieFragment extends Fragment
                                implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Movie>> {
private static final String TAG = "MovieFragment";
private static final String CURRENT_PAGE = "current_page";
private static final int LOADER_ID = 0;
private static final int START_PAGE = 1;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private List<Movie> mMovies = new ArrayList<>();
private MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;
public int mCurrentPage;

protected abstract Loader<List<Movie>> getLoader(int currentPage);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        mCurrentPage = savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_PAGE, 0);
    }else {
        mCurrentPage = START_PAGE;
    }
    startLoading();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.popular_recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener recyclerViewScrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
            mCurrentPage++;
            restartLoading();
        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(recyclerViewScrollListener);

    setupAdapter();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();
    getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(LOADER_ID);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(CURRENT_PAGE, mCurrentPage);
}

private void setupAdapter(){
    if (isAdded()){
        mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(mMovies);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
    }
}

private void startLoading(){
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}

private void restartLoading(){
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<List<Movie>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return getLoader(mCurrentPage);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Movie>> loader, List<Movie> data) {
    if (!data.isEmpty()){
        mMovies.addAll(data);
        mMovieAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mMovies.size() - 1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Movie>> loader) {
}

public static abstract class MovieLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Movie>> {

    protected abstract List<Movie> getMovie();

    public MovieLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading(){
        cancelLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Movie> loadInBackground() {
        return getMovie();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Что такое 5 страница и при возвращении откуда на фрагмент 5 страница загружается снова? не совсем понятна проблема

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, в RecyclerView в ходе скролинга подгружаються с сервиса новые страницы, вот пример url: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&language=en&page=1, при возвращении на фрагмент снова происходит загрузка, и как следствие дублирование данных